# Python GTK CSS issues on Windows

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

10I'm trying to make use of GTK3+ on Windows.
The setup is Python 2.7 and GTK3+ (3.10.x) installed from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar
Which to me seemed like the easiest way to get it up and running, correct me if I'm wrong.

The following app works fine on Linux but on Windows the shading of the button is off and I cannot seem to change the color of the text, it just stays black.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.set_name('MyWindow')

# The Button
button = Gtk.Button("Click Me")
win.add(button)


win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

css = """
#MyWindow GtkButton {

    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #000;
    font: Sans 10;
    color: white;                   
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px grey inset;
    margin: 10px;
}
"""

style_provider.load_from_data(css)

Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
    Gdk.Screen.get_default(), 
    style_provider,     
    Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
)

win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Any ideas about what could be wrong here?

Comment: I believe Gtk is using a specific engine on Windows for theming, so that Gtk apps integrate properly to native UIs. IIRC, this engine does not accept all CSS properties, like linux engines do.

Comment: Forget that, Gtk3 theme for Windows should be pure CSS, not engine dependent: http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2011/11/25/gtk-work-on-windows/

Comment: Well that's good news though I wonder whats wrong here, did i not install it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure that in your settings.ini the theme Adwaita is not commented out, you can find it in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gnome\etc\gtk-3.0 (or similar prefix depending on your installation of python)

```
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name = Adwaita
#gtk-font-name = Arial 10
```